# Equation exceeds the page border in Latex

Tags: equations

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{tgbonum}                           
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{flexisym}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.25in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$$L\left(\Gamma_{(k,2k)};x\right)=\Psi(L(G_1))\Psi(L(G_2))-\Psi(L(G_1))\Psi(L_4(G_2))-\Psi(L(G_2))\Psi(L_3(G_1))=x(x-1)^{(6k-2)} \times\bigl(x^3-(3k+5)x^2+(2k^2+8k+7)x-(3+3k) \bigr)\times \bigl(x^2-(k+3)x+2\bigr)\bigl(x^2-(2k+4)x+1 \bigr)$$
\end{document}


I am trying to write this code in latex. But it does not fit in the page. How to do this?
```

Comment: How about breaking the equation over multiple lines?

Comment: How we can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[showframe,
            a4paper, total={6.25in, 9in}]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
L\left(\Gamma_{(k,2k)};x\right)
    & = \Psi(L(G_1))\Psi(L(G_2))-\Psi(L(G_1))\Psi(L_4(G_2))-\Psi(L(G_2))\Psi(L_3(G_1))  \\
    & = x(x-1)^{(6k-2)} \times\bigl(x^3-(3k+5)x^2+(2k^2+8k+7)x-(3+3k) \bigr)            \\
    &\qquad   \times \bigl(x^2-(k+3)x+2\bigr)\bigl(x^2-(2k+4)x+1 \bigr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Note: some package you load twice, `mathools` is supersede of `amsmath`, so you not need to load `amsmath` again, similarly is with fonts: `amssymb` also load `amsfonts` ...

Answer (score 0):

Several other options to include a line break in your equation are described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860145/how-can-i-have-linebreaks-in-my-long-latex-equations

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Unfortunately, several of the approaches  presented in the question you linked from stackoverflow are far from "best practices".  Answers on tex.sx will generally present options that are more stable, often with an explanation of why that is so.